# Install OpenJDK-fontfix problems

Tags: ubuntu

I want to put the font-fix for openjdk on the instructions: 
[instructions](https://github.com/achaphiv/ppa-fonts/blob/master/openjdk-fontfix/README.md#install) perform all commands, but after run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I get message that the latest version is already installed. But he had to reinstall it? why?

Comment: What should "pereustanvlivatsya" mean?

Comment: sorry, it's meant "reinstall"